# Excel vba code keeps running

Tags: excel, vba, macos, object, ms-word

I have this code that opens a Word Template from Excel and paste in values to bookmarks in the Word Template. The code runs fine, but every now and then the codes runs 6 times in a row. This I know because I have a prompt that stops the code so it is possible to edit the word document before sending it. Sometimes the prompt pops up 6 times in a single run.
I think it has something to do with my error handling in the start of the code, see below. The code needs to be able to run both if word is running or not. Thanks in advance for taking time to look at this.

```
Dim objWord As Object

On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If objWord Is Nothing Then
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

On Error Resume Next
If objWord = 0 Then
Call WTWord
End If
```

This is the full code, that reference to functions and scripts made by Ron de Bruin http://www.rondebruin.nl/

```
Sub WTWord()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objSelection As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Folderstring As String
    Dim FilePathName As String
    Dim strbody As String

If CheckAppleScriptTaskExcelScriptFile(ScriptFileName:="RDBMacOutlook.scpt") = False Then
        MsgBox "Sorry the RDBMacOutlook.scpt is not in the correct location"
        Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If objWord Is Nothing Then
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

objWord.Visible = False
objDoc.Visible = False
objSelection.Visible = False

On Error Resume Next
If objWord = 0 Then
Call WTWord
End If

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("KONTRAKT.dotx")

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Dim Navn As Excel.Range
Dim Adresse As Excel.Range

    FolderName = "PDFSaveFolder"
    FileName = objDoc.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".pdf"

    Folderstring = CreateFolderinMacOffice2016(NameFolder:=FolderName)
    FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & FileName

Set Navn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set Adresse = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

With objDoc.Bookmarks
.Item("NAVN1").Range.InsertAfter Navn
.Item("ADRESSE1").Range.InsertAfter Adresse
End With

Dim YN As String
Dim Que As String

Que = "Vil du tilføje eller ændre noget i kontrakten?"
ThisWorkbook.Activate

YN = MsgBox(Que, vbYesNo, "KONTRAKT")

If YN = vbYes Then

Word.Application.Activate

Set objWord = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objSelections = Nothing

Exit Sub

Else

objDoc.SaveAs2 FilePathName, 17

objDoc.Close saveChanges:=False
objWord.Quit

    strbody = "<FONT size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">"

    strbody = strbody & "Hi there" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
     "This is line 1" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 2" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 3" & "<br>" & _
        "This is line 4"

    strbody = strbody & "</FONT>"

    MacExcel2016WithMacOutlookPDF _
    subject:="This is a test macro to mail the Activesheet as PDF", _
    mailbody:=strbody, _
    toaddress:="test@gmail.com", _
    ccaddress:="", _
    bccaddress:="", _
    displaymail:="yes", _
    accounttype:="", _
    accountname:="", _
    attachment:=FilePathName

End If
Exit Sub

Set objWord = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objSelections = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: what, exactly, is your question? The subject says one thing, but there^s nothing about that topic in your text...

Comment: Sorry, Have changed the title now. But I think the problem is caused by the checking if word is running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The socond Error Resume Next is not needed as this was not changed since the last one. For the 3 lines below this you have to remove that as this is calling it’s own sub. I would put the whole finding word code in a while loop and repeat this until objWord is not 0.

```
Dim objWord As Object

Do While objWord = 0
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   If objWord Is Nothing Then
      Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks it is working! Made a little change, got an error on "Do While" so I put it under "On Error Resume Next" now it works.

Comment: Glad it’s working now. Also you shouldn’t really use resume next to get rid of errors. What error did you get on the do while loop? Presumably something with comparing an object to 0?

Comment: I got Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. Isn't 0 = Nothing? I tried the code with "nothing" but got an error.

Comment: I think you have to set objWord = Nothing before the while loop. Also, after the getobject line you should put ‘On Error GoTo 0’ otherwise any errors in your code which needs fixing will be ignored. I’m also wondering if this needs to be in a while loop? After creating the object it should exist. You could check with a msg box how many times the loop runs, if it’s only once you most likely don’t need the while loop.

Comment: We can't fix this issue the right way for now, because there is a bug in the Mac Office 2016. So I need to "jump" over the error for now. see this tread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_mac-msoinsider_excel/trying-to-open-word-from-excel-vba-results-in-run/856d9a54-cc92-4ad8-9f49-cae38e7335b7